# php xml. remove only comment <!-- keep tags and values

Tags: php, xml

have a xml file that i read with php. In there is a commented section that i wanna read like it wasnt a comment, like it was real in the xml structure. For example:

```
$xml_str = "<test><tag></tag></test> <!-- <report><tag1>test</tag1><tag2>test2</tag2></report> -->";
```

How can i do this, that i remove the  tag from report? With

```
foreach ($xpath->query('//comment()') as $comment)
{
    var_dump($comment->textContent);
}
```

i have only the text strings but not the tags and so on. Uncommenting it when reading the file would be great

Comment: @NicoHaase─ that looks very similar to the code OP has.

Comment: Looking at the output in a browser may be misleading as the value from your code is `<report><tag1>test</tag1><tag2>test2</tag2></report>`

Comment: The code from the other question does not work. I wanna remove <!-- and --> so that i can iterate over <report> and so on. With the above code i dont have the <report> tag or the <tag1> tag for example.

Comment: You cannot "remove" those things. Instead, you can ask the XML processor for arbitrary comments which will give you raw text, and then you can put that text into a new XML processor. Comments that look like nodes are still comments.

Comment: Mhh ok. The i read the file and write a new temporary file without <!-- and --> and save it. Thought there was a xml way of this. thanks.

Comment: As @ChrisHaas says, you basically need to parse it twice. The first time round, extract the comment as a string, then submit the string as an XML document to an XML parser.

Comment: If your sure about your content (as in no reasonable value could look like a comment), you could just replace `<!--` and `-->` with blank in the string before parsing it.